# How to shutdown process with event loop and executor

Tags: python, python-multithreading, python-asyncio

Consider the following program.

```
import asyncio
import multiprocessing
from multiprocessing import Queue
from concurrent.futures.thread import ThreadPoolExecutor
import sys


def main():
    executor = ThreadPoolExecutor()
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    # comment the following line and the shutdown will work smoothly
    asyncio.ensure_future(print_some(executor))

    try:
        loop.run_forever()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print("shutting down")
        executor.shutdown()
        loop.stop()
        loop.close()
        sys.exit()


async def print_some(executor):
    print("Waiting...Hit CTRL+C to abort")
    queue = Queue()
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    some = await loop.run_in_executor(executor, queue.get)
    print(some)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

All I want is a graceful shutdown when I hit "CTRL+C". However, the executor thread seems to prevent that (even though I do call `shutdown`)

Comment: What do you mean "# comment the following line and the shutdown will work smoothly"? If you comment that line, you do nothing in executor. And what do you mean "graceful shutdown"? `shutdown` will join every workers, isn't that graceful?

Comment: Oh maybe I understand you, as `queue.get` is a blocking operation, so `shutdown` is hanged forever. You should first put a signal into `queue` to indicate it is over.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to send a poison pill to make the workers stop listening on the queue.get call. Worker threads in the `ThreadPoolExecutor` pool will block Python from exiting if they have active work. There's a [comment in the source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/concurrent/futures/thread.py#L16) that describes the reasoning for this behavior:

```
# Workers are created as daemon threads. This is done to allow the interpreter
# to exit when there are still idle threads in a ThreadPoolExecutor's thread
# pool (i.e. shutdown() was not called). However, allowing workers to die with
# the interpreter has two undesirable properties:
#   - The workers would still be running during interpreter shutdown,
#     meaning that they would fail in unpredictable ways.
#   - The workers could be killed while evaluating a work item, which could
#     be bad if the callable being evaluated has external side-effects e.g.
#     writing to a file.
#
# To work around this problem, an exit handler is installed which tells the
# workers to exit when their work queues are empty and then waits until the
# threads finish.
```

Here's a complete example that exits cleanly:

```
import asyncio
import multiprocessing
from multiprocessing import Queue
from concurrent.futures.thread import ThreadPoolExecutor
import sys


def main():
    executor = ThreadPoolExecutor()
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    # comment the following line and the shutdown will work smoothly
    fut = asyncio.ensure_future(print_some(executor))

    try:
        loop.run_forever()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print("shutting down")
        queue.put(None)  # Poison pill
        loop.run_until_complete(fut)
        executor.shutdown()
        loop.stop()
        loop.close()


async def print_some(executor):
    print("Waiting...Hit CTRL+C to abort")
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    some = await loop.run_in_executor(executor, queue.get)
    print(some)


queue = None
if __name__ == '__main__':
    queue = Queue()
    main()
```

The `run_until_complete(fut)` call is needed to avoid a warning about a pending task hanging around when the asyncio eventloop exits. If you don't care about that, you can leave that call out.

Comment: Ah! Thank you. So basically if you execute something in a `ThreadPoolExecutor` you need to design it to be stoppable (e.g through some condition) in order for the work to finish to eventually let the daemon get shut down.

Comment: @Christoph Yep, exactly.

Comment: I wonder if there's a way to contact you. Other than abusing a github issue on aioprocessing ;) email / twitter?